# I am getting error on save() method of a model

Tags: model

I am getting this error on save method of a model.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function beginTransaction() on a
>   non-object in
>   /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php on line
>   313

```
$warranty = Mage::getModel('warrany/warrantydata');
$warranty->setOrderId($order_id);
$warranty->setSignifydScore($signifyd_score);
$warranty->setSignifydData(utf8_encode(serialize($data)));
$warranty->save();
```

I have this added xml for model

```
    <models>
    <warranty>
      <class>Website_Warranty_Model</class>
      <resourceModel>warranty_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </warranty>
       <warranty_mysql4>
              <class>Website_Warranty_Model_Mysql4</class>
          <entities>
            <warrantydata>
               <table>warrantydata</table>
        </warrantydata>
          </entities>
          </warranty_mysql4>
   </models>
```

i also have the collection and model file

```
class Website_Warranty_Model_Warrantydata extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract{}

class Website_Warranty_Model_Mysql4_Warrantydata extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract {}
```

Comment: Could you please add some more information?
- What does your config.xml look like?
- Did you create the class in the Model folder?

Comment: It seams obvious...`$this->_getRsource()` does not return an object

Answer (score 2):

In your resource model `Website_Warranty_Model_Mysql4_Warrantydata` you need to add this method :

```
public function _construct(){
    $this->_init('warranty/warrantydata', 'entity_id'); //the second parameter must be the primary key in your warrantydata table. If it's not `entity_id` then change it
}
```

and in your model class `Website_Warranty_Model_Warrantydata` you need this method:

```
public function _construct(){
    parent::_construct();
    $this->_init('warranty/warrantydata');
}
```